# See current method name in Micro Framework

Tags: c#, .net-micro-framework

How can I see the current method name in Micro Framework? I know of these two options, but they are for Windows Framework:

1.

```
MethodBase method = (new StackTrace(true)).GetFrame(0).GetMethod();
string methodname = method.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + method.Name;
```

2.

```
MethodBase method = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod();
string methodname = method.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + method.Name;
```

**EDITED:** There is another way, but neither works in Micro Framework:

3.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
// get call stack
StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
// get calling method name
Console.WriteLine(stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name);
```

Comment: I'm working on a log saver class.

Comment: I've added a new method, that neither works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this using reflection...i know how to do using CSLA framework but i think this will not help you now.

This link may help you : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Good luck trying.